# Extracting log files inside Docker container as non-root

Tags: docker

I've been playing with dockers for a while now, and I had a problem extracting log files directory of a service that runs within container.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
ENV HOME=/software/service
ENV LOGS=$HOME/logs
COPY Service.jar $HOME/Service.jar
WORKDIR HOME
CMD java -jar Service.jar
```

I created a stub service for this that all he does is creating logfile name `log.log` inside `LOGS` environment variable and writes to it every 2 seconds.

What I wanted to achieve is to backup the `log.log` file inside my docker linux host. After some reading about multiple options I came across 2 popular solutions for persisting data:

1. Using volumes with the `docker run -v` options
2. Creating a data container that holds the data

Option 2 will not help much here since I want to view the logs inside my linux host machine so I chose option 1.

The problem with option 1 is it's creating the logs with a `root` permissions, which means I have to log into root to be able to delete these logs, something which can cause problem when not everyone should have root user and deleting logs is something that happens commonly.

So I read a little more and find many "work arounds" for this problem, one was mounting my `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd` files inside the docker and use `-u` option and others were similar to this.

My main question is, is there any convenient and standard solution for this issue, extract the logfiles with/without `-v` option while letting entire group permission to `rwx` it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the logs to be in your host you need some kind of volume sharing and the "-v" flag is definitely the simplest thing you can do.

As per the permissions issue, I see two options:

1. the `-u` flag with passwd/group bindmounting that you mentioned
2. passing the desired username and group IDs as environment variables and make the daemon running in the docker machine chown the file upon creation (but of course this is not always possible).

I think option 1, while tricky, is the easiest to apply.

Comment: When i'm trying option 1, I get error in container says permission denied while trying to create the logs directory, using the command:

`docker run -ti \
-v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro \
-u $( id -u $USER ):$( id -g $USER ) \
my-image:lastest`

Maybe I missed something?

Comment: what is this log directory? Of course, if you run your container with an unprivileged user you have to check permissions. Try logging in /tmp for example

Comment: The log directory is specified in the `Dockerfile` under /software/service/logs, but why shouldn't I be able to create it?

Comment: In a linux system, you usually cannot write under / as long as you are not root. You can add `RUN mkdir -p /software/service/logs && chmod 777 /software/service/logs` in your dockerfile for example, or choose a directory inside user's home direcory (which should be writable by default, without the need for a chown)

Comment: After playing for a little longer with this I still don't understand why the /software/service/logs inside my container is created by root (when I `docker exec ls -l /software/service/logs` since the `java -jar Service.jar` is creating that folder which is ran by my user

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to simply copy the logs to the host:

```
docker cp <container-name>:/software/service/logs .
```

Comment: This option won't suit much because when the container will crash I might lose logs